# SignalR Broadcast Messages Duplicated after Stop/Start

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, signalr

Messages sent to the client by the hub are replicated for each time I have stop/started the connection.

If I execute this sequence:
$.connection.hub.stop()
$.connection.hub.start() {...}

and send a message from the server hub to the client, the message is received one time.
If I reexecute the above sequence, I will received the same message twice, even though the server hub calls 
     Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).acceptMsg(msg);
only 1 time. acceptMsg is invoked twice at the client for the same message with the connectionId.
I get the same results using Clients.All.acceptMsg(msg)

For each subsequent stop/start, the message is further duplicated; three messages the third time, four messages the fourth, etc.

I have tried separating invocation of the stop and start by a couple of minutes but it made no difference.

Other details: Javascript client, SignalR v2.0.1, Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63, ASP.Net 4.5. SignalR is utilizing long-polling in my test and I am allowing the default negotiation. In the SignalR trace, "SignalR: Aborted xhr request." is observed after the stop, before the start.

Any idea what is causing my messages to be replicated in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been fixed in the coming 2.0.2 release.  Here's the GitHub issue for reference: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2595